# Non-Bitcoin transactions on the Blockchain

Tags: transactions, cryptography, bitcoin, blockchain

I'm Interested in the application of non-financial transactions using the blockchain.

I have read about Null Data (OP_RETURN) Transactions. These transactions allow up to 40 bytes of arbitrary data to be added onto a transaction to the blockchain, but this still involves the transfer of currency.

So I'm looking for a way of using the blockchain without having to transfer any currency. Is this possible?

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Any documentation/APIs would be really useful.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to send at least a satoshi and have to pay a transaction fee if you are using op_return. I don't think there are any miners left who will process those for free.

You can use the test net block chain for free transactions.

In the future the value you will be able to send could be fractions of a cent and essentially free, but not yet.

Answer (score 1):

Zeronet.io combines principles of ipfs with namecoin ,
and offers a script when run
opens a localhost in browser
where the script serves a zeronet node.
no wallet creation was necessary.

Comment: Both this question and answer shouldn't be on SO